# java.sql.SQLException:No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB

Tags: java, mysql, maven, tomcat, jdbc

I am facing same problem. I am using following db url fetched from pom.xml file

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB?autoReconnect=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

and driver class is : `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource`

when I deploy war of my application in tomcat and hit the url, it gives error :

```
java.sql.SQLException:No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDB?autoReconnect=true&createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
```

but if I start tomcat in eclipse and hit the url, I never get such error. It's working as expected.

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you try using the driver `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`?

Comment: `MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` is not a `Driver` class

Answer (score 2):

Add the following dependency to your pom:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.26</version>
</dependency>
```

and the jar to `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` folder.

Answer (score 2):

When you run your app from Eclipse, you are running it in a special test tomcat container and eclipse is setting everything up for you.

When you run your app in Tomcat outside Eclipse, you must set up all required libraries yourself.  This includes ensuring that the JDBC drivers are available.  You need to place the JDBC drivers jar file into `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` folder for them to be picked up correctly.

Have a look at the [tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html), specifically, section *MySQL DBCP Example*.

Comment: But I am using maven dependency and I have mentioned mysql-connector-java dependency in pom.xml file.

Comment: @user2664210 Using maven you can only package the drivers with the app - but you **must** install them into the `TOMCAT_HOME/lib` directory.  Have a look at [tomcat documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html), specifically _MySQL DBCP Example_ section.

Comment: I have copied mysql-connector-java.jar into tomcat/lib and also mentioned <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
   <version>5.0.5</version>
  </dependency>in pom.xml , still giving same problem

Comment: Can you send details of how your data source is set up?

Comment: I am reading these values from property file.                Properties config = CommonPropertiesUtil.getInstance();
   Class.forName(config.getProperty(CommonConstants.PROP_JDBC_DRIVER));
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(config.getProperty(CommonConstants.PROP_DB_URL),     config.getProperty(CommonConstants.PROP_DB_USERNAME),
config.getProperty(CommonConstants.PROP_DB_PASSWORD));